# MassTransit.Analyzers not picking up potential issues

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 web API project that references MassTransit.Analyzers v7.0.3 and in my message consumer I have the following code but the analyzer isn't picking up any issues. I tried adding a random property within the anonymous object but I get the same result. No errors or warnings.

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IGetUser> context)
{
    await context.RespondAsync<IGetUserResponse>(new
    {
    });
}
```

```
public interface IGetUserResponse
{
    string FirstName { get; }

    string LastName { get; }

    string UserName { get; }
}
```

EDIT:

Here are the list of analyzers I have in my project.

[image]

Comment: Which editor? And you should remove the `set;` property accessor from your interface. Also, I just verified the 7.0.3 analyzer works as expected.

Comment: I am using VS 2019.

Comment: All I have to do is to include the package into my project right? I watched one of your videos and that's all you did. Not sure if it's maybe colliding with some of my other analyzers.

Comment: Not sure, I created a new project, installed both MassTransit and MassTransit.Analyzers NuGet packages, and doing the same `RespondAsync` code you have above was given the prompt to add missing properties to the initializer.

Comment: Found the issue. I had to add it into my stylecop.ruleset file. Thanks for the awesome library, @ChrisPatterson

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if you're using Directory.Build.props with stylecop.ruleset in it, you will have to specify MassTransit rules in it for it to recognize potential issues within your code.

I added the lines below and now I am getting a Warning if I missed a property on my response.

```
    <Rules AnalyzerId="MassTransit.Analyzers" RuleNamespace="MassTransit.Analyzers">
        <Rule Id="MCA0001" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="MCA0002" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="MCA0003" Action="Warning" />
        <Rule Id="MTA0001" Action="Warning" />
    </Rules>
```